# Copy S3 object to another S3 location Elastic Beanstalk SSH setup error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

Getting this Elastic Beanstalk permission error when trying to do:

```
eb ssh --setup
```

```
2020-07-06 07:36:50    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-07-06 07:36:53    ERROR   Service:Amazon S3, Message:You don't have permission to copy an Amazon S3 object to another S3 location. Source: bucket = 'tempsource', key = 'xxx'. Destination: bucket = 'tempdest', key = 'yyy'.
2020-07-06 07:36:53    ERROR   Failed to deploy configuration.
```

Is there a specific policy that I should be adding to my IAM permissions? I've tried adding full S3 access to my IAM User, but the error remains. Or is a permissions error associated with the source bucket?

**Some more details:**

Both buckets are in the same AWS account. The copying operation doesn't work for AWS CLI copy commands.

**Bucket Profiles**

Source Bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOURCE_BUCKET/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOURCE_BUCKET"
        }
    ]
}
```

Destination Bucket (elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXXXX)

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "eb-ad78f54a-f239-4c90-adda-49e5f56cb51e",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXXXX/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resources/environments/logs/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "eb-af163bf3-d27b-4712-b795-d1e33e331ca4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resources/environments/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "eb-58950a8c-feb6-11e2-89e0-0800277d041b",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried adding full S3 access to my IAM User, but the error remains.

The error is not about about your IAM permissions (i.e. your IAM user). But its about a role that EB is using your the instance (i.e. **instance role/profile**):

- [Managing Elastic Beanstalk instance profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html)

The defualt role used on the instances in `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`. Thus you can locate it in IAM console, and add required S3 permissions. Depending on your setup, you may be using different role.

> Or is a permissions error associated with the source bucket?

If you have bucket policies that deny the access, it could also be the reason.

Comment: Ah that makes some sense. However, I checked that I am using the EC2 instance role, and this role also has S3FullAccess. As for the bucket policies, it does look like I have GetObject access in my source bucket and PutObject access in my destination bucket. Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: @AlanJi Its difficult to speculate without more details. Are the buckets in the same account? What are the principles in the bucket policies? Are there any conditions on the policies? Does copying operation work from other instance (non-EB) one, thus is the access denied limited only to this one EB environment? You can update the question with new details.

Comment: @AlanJi Thanks. Have you checked if the issue remains if the policies are removed? This would ensure that the issue is due to these policies, not the EB application.

Comment: Looks like this issue still remains even if I delete the policies.

Comment: I've tried instead to directly ssh into my EB environment (without the setup flag), which works.

Comment: @AlanJi Must be then something with you app. Are you sure it does not use any hard-coded credentials or roles?

Comment: Didn't exactly find a solution, but I'm just going ahead with ssh directly into the environment. Thanks for all of the help so far.